# Issues with activity group

Tags: android

I have an app in which I am implementing a tab bar with 3 tabs. In first tab I am implementing multiple activities by using activity group.

In this activity group I have 5 activities. In the first activity I am having edit texts, I am getting the data into edit texts from another class and then navigating to another activity by clicking a button. When I am coming back from second activity to first activty I am not able to see the selected data. It is showing the page without selected data.

I don't understand this.

Comment: I'm not sure if people can help you without any code. We can't see your app.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityGroup.html):

> This class is deprecated...

And now coming to your question, you said:

> ... When i am coming back from second activity to first activty i am not
>   able to see the selected data...

It is default behavior of `ActivityGroup`, when you move forward, your current `Activity`'s state is not saved and when you come back to previous `Activity`, it is started again and `onCreate()` is called again.

Comment: You have to save the state of your `Activity`. and remember `onCreate()` is always called. which means you can't use traditional way of saving `Activity` state. (_i.e onSaveInstanceState() will not work_)

Answer (score 0):

its because, in Activity Group Implementation, all the activities are re-created and then generates view, and then adding this view in window activity is displayed. So, everytime a new activity is displayed, as activities are re-created.

Comment: Use Fragments instead of ActivityGroup.